# Web3 JS Library (& Metamask), Get Token Balance

Tags: web3js, abi

I want to query the eth balance and all token balances of a public key. So far I managed to load `web3` and call the `getBalance` method.

Now, I want to see the balance for ERC20 tokens which are stored with the same public key? E.g. I want to see the balance of `OMG` tokens?

So far I found that each token contract address has to be queried:
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/15372/how-can-i-view-all-the-tokens-and-contracts-associated-with-an-ethereum-address

```
omgContractAddress = "0xd26114cd6EE289AccF82350c8d8487fedB8A0C07"
OmgContract = web3.eth.contract(abi)
omgContract = OmgContract.at(omgContractAddress)
someUsersAddress = "0x75087d9faa28d653750f3e4c86e7dcf6aff0a916"
omgContract.balanceOf someUsersAddress, (err, balance)-> #some owner
        console.error err
        console.info balance.toNumber()
```

Questions:

1) Do I need the `abi` of each token? Or can I use a standardized `abi` for ERC20 tokens as long as I just want to use standardized methods?

2) Where do I find the `abi`? Or do I need to recompile each contract?

E.g. OMG: https://etherscan.io/token/OmiseGo

Comment: You also can [use rpc to get the balance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49998988/6521116)

Answer (score 4):

I could find the `abi`s of several tokens on `https://etherscan.io/address/<token_address>#code` so far they have the same method common in their `abi`. I just copied the method directly into my source code without reading the original `abi`. E.g.

```
abi = [{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_owner","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"}]
```