# Get token balance with Ethereum RPC?

Tags: php, token, blockchain, ethereum

how display balance of token through Ethereum RPC?

```
$id = 0;
$data = array();
$data['jsonrpc'] = '2.0';
$data['id'] = $id++;
$data['method'] = 'eth_call';
$data['params'] = [['from' => '0x0...', 'to' => '0x0...', 'data' => 'contract byte code here 0x0...'], 'latest'];

$ch = curl_init();
...
```

Return:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":0,"result":"0x"}
```

What to do next? Call contract method balanceOf? How to do that?

Comment: "how display balance of token through Ethereum" seem like good terms for web searches.

Comment: I've Googled and Googled and there's nothing. There's a bunch of Stack Overflow questions on how to do it with existing libraries, but there's literally no documentation on how to do it with raw Json. I'm using C# so none of the samples are of any use to me.

Answer (score 24):

To get token balance with `eth_call` you need `to` and `data` parameter. `to` is contract address, here we need to generate the `data` parameter. As the doc [eth_call](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_call) says,

> data: DATA - (optional) Hash of the method signature and encoded
>   parameters. For details see [Ethereum-Contract-ABI](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethereum-Contract-ABI)

Take this [EOS token transaction](https://etherscan.io/token/0x86fa049857e0209aa7d9e616f7eb3b3b78ecfdb0?a=0x0b88516a6d22bf8e0d3657effbd41577c5fd4cb7) as a example.

Contract address:`0x86fa049857e0209aa7d9e616f7eb3b3b78ecfdb0`

Token Holder address:`0x0b88516a6d22bf8e0d3657effbd41577c5fd4cb7`

You can see the contract code [here](https://etherscan.io/address/0x86fa049857e0209aa7d9e616f7eb3b3b78ecfdb0#code).

```
contract ERC20 {
    function totalSupply() constant returns (uint supply);
    function balanceOf( address who ) constant returns (uint value);
    function allowance( address owner, address spender ) constant returns (uint _allowance);

    function transfer( address to, uint value) returns (bool ok);
    function transferFrom( address from, address to, uint value) returns (bool ok);
    function approve( address spender, uint value ) returns (bool ok);

    event Transfer( address indexed from, address indexed to, uint value);
    event Approval( address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint value);
}
```

[Function Selector](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethereum-Contract-ABI#function-selector)

```
>>> from web3 import Web3
>>> Web3.sha3("balanceOf(address)")
HexBytes('0x70a08231b98ef4ca268c9cc3f6b4590e4bfec28280db06bb5d45e689f2a360be')
```

Take the first four bytes `70a08231`

[Argument Encoding](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethereum-Contract-ABI#argument-encoding)

> address: equivalent to uint160, except for the assumed interpretation
>   and language typing.
>
> int: enc(X) is the big-endian two's complement encoding of X,
>   padded on the higher-order (left) side with 0xff for negative X and
>   with zero bytes for positive X such that the length is a multiple of
>   32 bytes.

Padding the 20 bytes token address to 32 bytes with `0` to token holder address:

```
0000000000000000000000000b88516a6d22bf8e0d3657effbd41577c5fd4cb7
```

Then concat the function selector and encoded parameter, we get `data` parameter:

0x70a082310000000000000000000000000b88516a6d22bf8e0d3657effbd41577c5fd4cb7

Make the request with:

```
curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_call","params":[{"to": "0x86fa049857e0209aa7d9e616f7eb3b3b78ecfdb0", "data":"0x70a082310000000000000000000000000b88516a6d22bf8e0d3657effbd41577c5fd4cb7"}, "latest"],"id":67}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://127.0.0.1:8545/
```

here is the curl result (You may get different answer here, as there may be some transaction with this address done after my polling the request)

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":67,"result":"0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000014a314d9ff9b20b9800"}
```

You can change convert hex format balance to decimal

```
>>> 0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000014a314d9ff9b20b9800
6090978215900000000000
```

Check the result,

[image]

Comment: Can we see this in Json please? I'm using C# so I can't use the library you are referring to here.

Answer (score 6):

When calling a Solidity contract function, in general, `data` should be the following, encoded as a hex string:

1. The "function selector," which is the first four bytes of the keccak-256 hash of the signature of the function you're calling.
2. The ABI-encoded arguments to the function you're calling.

The function signature for an ERC20 token's `balanceOf` is `balanceOf(address)`. The keccak-256 hash is `70a08231b98ef4ca268c9cc3f6b4590e4bfec28280db06bb5d45e689f2a360be`, so the first four bytes are `70a08231`.

The function only takes a single parameter: the address of the account whose balance you're trying to look up. To ABI-encode it, simply left-pad it with zeros until it's 32 bytes long. Since addresses are 20 bytes, this means adding 12 bytes of zeros (or 24 characters in hex).

So the full `data` field should be `"0x70a08231" + "000000000000000000000000" + address`.

Comment: [{"from":"0xC4cFCE18f7Eb59c6FA50F86Ca20596B661415597","to":"0xad21Ec955C1BB732778DE74B4a05199eC472Ffb3","data":"0xa9059cbb00000000000000000000000075149d823cbde9331bacb7c05ce20c6336b031860000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001"},"latest"]}

Comment: transfer(address,uint256). Return 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001. But tokens not transfering. Before this do unlock acc. What is wrong?

Comment: from its main acc, to contract addr

Answer (score 2):

May I recommend a proper ERC20 library for PHP that I have developed myself.

https://www.furqansiddiqui.com/libraries/erc20-php/

https://github.com/furqansiddiqui/erc20-php

**sample code to retrieve balance:**

```
<?php
$geth = new EthereumRPC('127.0.0.1', 8545);
$erc20 = new \ERC20\ERC20($geth);

// Pass ERC20 contract address as argument below
$token = $erc20->token('0xd26114cd6EE289AccF82350c8d8487fedB8A0C07');

var_dump($token->name()); # string(8) "OMGToken"
var_dump($token->symbol()); # string(3) "OMG"
var_dump($token->decimals()); # int(18)

var_dump($token->balanceOf('0x...')); // Enter ethereum address here
```

Answer (score 0):

For token transaction you need to use `eth_sendTransaction`.